# What is meaning of a flag being disputed or declined?

Tags: support, moderation, flagging

I have discovered that I can find out the fate of my flags by clicking on the relevant field in my profile where it tells me how many helpful flags I have raised. I understand what "helpful" means, but what is the difference between "disputed" and "declined"?

Note: this is not a complaint, false positives are almost inevitable in any realistic signal detection task.

Comment: See [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag) ... and ...
[What is the difference between disputed and declined flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141292/what-is-the-difference-between-disputed-and-declined-flags)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case @glen_b does not have time to answer and close the thread I am posting here his links
[What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag)
and
[What is the difference between disputed and declined flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141292/what-is-the-difference-between-disputed-and-declined-flags)

In the hope that others may learn from my two mistakes :

First mistake was to forget that this was likely to be an SE-wdie issue so serching as I did just on Meta-CV was not going to work.

Second mistake was not to think through what my area of ignorance really was. In fact reading the helpful linked posts it is clear that I did not really understand what happens to flags at all. I have subsequently re-read the description of the [Flag posts privilege](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)
which  has helped clear up some of my confusion.